# Retain aspect ratio for full height responsive image in Chrome

Tags: image, responsive-design, height, css

I've set an image to `max-height:100%;` of the browser window (with a small padding at the bottom), centred on the page. Currently, I'm having problems keeping the aspect ratio of the image from squashing when the browser is resized (interestingly it shows at the correct aspect ratio when refreshed after a resize).

I've set up an example in codepen. Would appreciate any advice on how to keep the ratio correct.

http://cdpn.io/sHJhl

UPDATE 18/08: I've updated the code in the copepen above. It's now working in all browsers except Chrome, which distorts the image when the browser is resized. Oddly it resizes fine in Chrome when the codepen is in edit mode. I've tested the code from the codepen in my development site and it shows the same issue, so it's definitely not a codepen quirk. Hoping someone can help on this one.

FURTHER UPDATE 18/08: Solved this issue with Chrome by adding `max-width:100%`, see answer below.

Comment: What browser is showing the issue? And at what size does it start to distort? Not seeing any issues in Chrome.

Comment: Chrome shows the issue for me. It distorts as soon as the browser is resized, though oddly it works fine in Chrome when the codepen is in edit mode. Firefox and Safari work fine. I've tested the code from the codepen in my development site and it shows the same issue, so it's definitely not a codepen quirk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved this issue. The image needed `max-width:100%;` as well as `max-height:100%; width:auto;` to work in Chrome. I've updated the codepen to show the full working code: http://cdpn.io/sHJhl

Answer (score 0):

Image's parent element `.photo-bkg` doesn't have any width set, so add it a `width: 100%;`

```
.photo-bkg { height:100%; width: 100%; }
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this didn't have any effect. Also tried adding `width:100%;` to all the parents, and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You want to achieve a full page background right?

This worked for me:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

source: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Thanks, this would be perfect but the image can't be cropped as the site I'm working on is for a photographer who's keen on displaying the images without any cropping.