# Chrome image distorted. Firefox OK

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In a Joomla website, Chrome is distorting an image width. The image is of a light bulb which is displayed OK in Firefox, but in Chrome the width is much reduced so that the bulb looks more like a matchstick :) The HTML is:

```
<p class="word_set">1
  <span class="color_up audio" id="b1e01">the</span>
  <span class="color_up audio" id="b1t01">คำนำหน้านามเจาะจง </span>
  <span class="ws_dialog_icon" id="wsd01">  
    <img class="wsd_img"  id="wsd_img01"  src="/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/lamp_non-hover_20.png" alt="light bulb" height="18px" width="18px"></span>
</p>
```

and the CSS:

```
img.wsd_img {
   /* background: red; */
  max-width: 100% !important;
  max-height: 100% !important;
  width: auto !important;
}
```

I got the CSS setting from this SO article  [Retain aspect ratio for full height responsive image in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252469/retain-aspect-ratio-for-full-height-responsive-image-in-chrome)  but I had tried other variations before, all to no avail. I know the CSS is referencing the correct HTML element because the red background (here commented out) shows up on the image in both browsers.  Browser versions - Firefox 43, Chrome 47.0.2526.105. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: provide a link to an online version

Comment: www,english2theworld.com

Comment: provide a link to the page u experience the problem with the image

Comment: Program Content>Word Learning>Word Sets>Word Set 1-10>Word Set 1

Comment: Anywhere within the Word Sets area, Firefox displays the lamp icon OK, Chrome doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of the `span` parent of each lamp. Add `display: inline-table` to its style definition:

```
p.word_set span, p.word_learn span, p.thai2eng span{
    display: inline-table;
}
```

Comment: Hi Trix,  it works, end of frustrating search for a solution, many thanks, have a nice festive season

Comment: I checked out this SO article "What is the difference between inline-block and inline-table?" But I'm not altogether sure why display: inline-table works here but display: inline-block doesn't. UPDATE:  I got it thanks